# If e is idempotent, prove that 1-e is as well.

Tags: ring-theory, idempotents

Let $(R,+,·)$ be a ring with unity. If $e$ is idempotent, prove that $1-e$ is also idempotent.

Here's my attempt:
If $e$ is idempotent then $e^n=e$. Then
$$e=e^n$$
$$e-e^n=0$$
$$e(1-e^{n-1})=0$$
$$1-e^{n-1}=0$$
But $e^{n-1}=e$, so:
$$1-e=0$$
which means $1-e$ is idempotent. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you conclude $1-e^{n-1}=0$ from $e(1-e^{n-1})=0$?

Comment: If $e$ is idempotent, then in general, $e^{n-1}\ne e$, and certainly your conclusion $1-e=0$ does not hold. Actually, idempotence is usually defined as $e^2=e$. So perhaps tyr to expand and simplify the expression $(1-e)^2$ and hopefully arrive at $1-e$.

Comment: If $e$ is idempotent, the $e^2=e.$ Use this fact to compute $(1-e)^2.$

Comment: @leoli1 because if $e(1-e^{n-1})=0$ then either $e$ or $1-e^{n-1}$ is $0$, in this case I chose the most beneficial case.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - Sorry. I think we were typing at the same time. Unfortunately, I'm a bit slow at it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn't idempotence valid for any power? That's what my professor told me.

Comment: "*If $e(1-e^{n-1})=0$ then either $e$ or $1-e^{n-1}$ is $0$*"  No, that is false.  You are thinking of an Integral Domain.  This is not true for general rings, only true for very specific types of rings.  Take for example $(\Bbb Z_8,+_8,\times_8)$ where you have $2\times 4 = 0$ but neither $2$ nor $4$ are zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah ok, good to know

Comment: As for "*isn't idempotence valid for any power?*"  Given the hypothesis that $e=e^2$ it follows from induction that $e^n=e$ for *every* integer $n\geq 1$.  Do not confuse this with the hypothesis that $e^n=e$ for *some* positive integer $n$ but not necessarily all.  For instance in $\Bbb Z$ you have $(-1)^3=(-1)$ however $(-1)^4\neq (-1)$.

Comment: Next critique... "*if $e(1-e^{n-1})=0$ then either $e$ or $1-e^{n-1}$ is $0$, in this case I chose the most beneficial case*"  Ignoring the fact that we aren't actually in an integral domain since I already mentioned that... you don't get to *choose* which of those was zero based on preference... both are possibilities and both possibilities would need to be fully explored.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that throughout your question, $n = 2$.

No, that is not correct, because given that $e (1 - e) = 0$, we cannot conclude that either $e = 0$ or $1 - e = 0$. It's possible for both $e$ and $1 - e$ to be nonzero, and yet for $e (1 - e)$ to be $0$ nevertheless.

For example, in the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices (where $0$ denotes the zero matrix and $1$ denotes the identity matrix),

$$1 - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end {bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end {bmatrix} \ne 0,$$

and yet

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end {bmatrix} \left (1 - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end {bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end {bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end {bmatrix} = 0.$$

However, in any ring, $(1 - e)^2 = (1 - e)(1 - e) = 1 - 2 e + e^2$. Since $e^2 = e$, what can you conclude from this?